# How to get only json string

Tags: json

```
<div class="body-layout" id="wide-wrapper">
<div id="wrap-all">some content will be there
    {"success":1,"message":"Data Success","data":[{"title":"RECRUITMENT IN NATIONAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED (NICL)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 205, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-national-insurance-company-limited-nicl-0"},{"title":"RECRUITMENT OF PO IN BANK OF BARODA (BOB)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 400, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-po-bank-baroda-bob"},{"title":"SBI PO Prelims Admit Card 2017","disp":"SBI PO 2017 Admit Card for, we hide [...]","link":"\/sbi-po-prelims-admit-card-2017"}]}         
</div>
```

How can i get only json string from the above content, is there any regular expression to filter.

Comment: which language is currently  using in your project

Comment: wrap the string inside it's own div.

Comment: can you show us an example on how, you want to use this in your php

Answer (score 1):

**One liner answer :**

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("wrap-all").innerHTML;

console.log(JSON.parse(elem.substring(elem.indexOf('{'), elem.lastIndexOf('}')+1)));
```

```html
<div class="body-layout" id="wide-wrapper">
<div id="wrap-all">some content will be there
    {"success":1,"message":"Data Success","data":[{"title":"RECRUITMENT IN NATIONAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED (NICL)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 205, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-national-insurance-company-limited-nicl-0"},{"title":"RECRUITMENT OF PO IN BANK OF BARODA (BOB)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 400, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-po-bank-baroda-bob"},{"title":"SBI PO Prelims Admit Card 2017","disp":"SBI PO 2017 Admit Card for, we hide [...]","link":"\/sbi-po-prelims-admit-card-2017"}]}  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your string inside a div and use a selector to get text of the div.

```
<div class="body-layout" id="wide-wrapper">
<div id="wrap-all">
 some content will be there
<div class="json">
    {"success":1,"message":"Data Success","data":[{"title":"RECRUITMENT IN NATIONAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED (NICL)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 205, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-national-insurance-company-limited-nicl-0"},{"title":"RECRUITMENT OF PO IN BANK OF BARODA (BOB)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 400, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-po-bank-baroda-bob"},{"title":"SBI PO Prelims Admit Card 2017","disp":"SBI PO 2017 Admit Card for, we hide [...]","link":"\/sbi-po-prelims-admit-card-2017"}]}
</div>         
</div>
```

Use `textContent` with  `javascript`. `textContent` property represents the text content of a node and its descendants. [MDN textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or you can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```
<script>
    var str = document.getElementById('json').textContent;
    var json = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(json);
</script>
```

**Console log screenshot**
[image]

Comment: using php i need to get

Answer (score 0):

If your not able to alter the text in your div then you can use **[regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)** **[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** method to match particular string.

`/{\s*\".*}/g` to march JSON format in given string which will - start with `{` end with `{` and contrails any character in the middle

**`{`** - start with `{`

**`\s*\".*`** - it will allow **space , ", any word** in the middle

**`}`** - end with `}`

```js
var str = document.getElementById('wrap-all').innerHTML;
var JsonStr = matchExact(str);
    console.log(JsonStr);
function matchExact(str) {
 var r = /{\s*\".*}/g
   var match = str.match(r);
   return match != null && match[0];
}
```

```html
<div class="body-layout" id="wide-wrapper">
<div id="wrap-all">some content will be there
    {"success":1,"message":"Data Success","data":[{"title":"RECRUITMENT IN NATIONAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED (NICL)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 205, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-national-insurance-company-limited-nicl-0"},{"title":"RECRUITMENT OF PO IN BANK OF BARODA (BOB)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 400, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-po-bank-baroda-bob"},{"title":"SBI PO Prelims Admit Card 2017","disp":"SBI PO 2017 Admit Card for, we hide [...]","link":"\/sbi-po-prelims-admit-card-2017"}]}         
</div>
```

**[Working example in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/L3hgk348/3/)**

Answer (score -1):

use  strip_tags() function

```
 <?php
$string = '<div class="body-layout" id="wide-wrapper">
<div id="wrap-all">
{"success":1,"message":"Data Success","data":[{"title":"RECRUITMENT IN NATIONAL INSURANCE COMPANY LIMITED (NICL)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 205, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-national-insurance-company-limited-nicl-0"},{"title":"RECRUITMENT OF PO IN BANK OF BARODA (BOB)","disp":"RECRUITMENT OF 400, we hide [...]","link":"\/recruitment-po-bank-baroda-bob"},{"title":"SBI PO Prelims Admit Card 2017","disp":"SBI PO 2017 Admit Card for, we hide [...]","link":"\/sbi-po-prelims-admit-card-2017"}]}         
</div>';
echo strip_tags($string);
?>
```